# Nuget dll hell : How to solve "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.5.4.0"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I have a test project that references a dll project; this dll project references itself Azure Nugets, especially Azure.Storage.Blobs (v12.9.1)
One of my tests fails when reaching this instruction :

`var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);`

Exception is :

```
System.IO.FileLoadException
  HResult=0x80131040
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
  Source=Azure.Storage.Blobs
  StackTrace:
   at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobServiceClient..ctor(String connectionString, BlobClientOptions options)
   at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobServiceClient..ctor(String connectionString)
  (…)

Inner Exception 1:
FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I would like to understand and solve this exception.

Notes :

- UnitTest Project is using .Net Framework 4.7.2
- Referenced project is using .Net standard 2.0, and references itself other projects.
- System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions is neither referenced explicitly by my test project, nor by referenced dll.

What I already investigated :

1. Add bindingredirect in Test Project App.Config :

```xml
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.4.0" newVersion="4.5.4.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
```

Note : For the next steps of my investigation, I kept this binding redirect

2. Check that System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll is present in test project bin/debug folder => It is the case, this dll is present. Note : I don't know how to detrmine its nuget version (details in windows explorer only gives dll version)
3. Adding a reference to nuget System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions v4.5.4.0 (latest version) to unit test project
4. Adding a reference to nuget System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions v4.5.4.0 (latest version) to referenced project

Thanks for help.

Comment: Try to change `bindingRedirect` to `oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.4"`, `newVersion="4.5.4"` and see if this works. If not, try to change it to `oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.1"`, `newVersion="4.2.0.1"`. Also, try to clear the NuGet cache(Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings > Clear All NuGet Cache).

Comment: Applying oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.1", newVersion="4.2.0.1" solved the problem. Thank you Tianyu. It does not make sense for me because the 4.2 is not a nuget version I install. And why minor version ".1"?

Comment: There are some differences, the 4.2.0.1 is the newest assembly version of `System.Threading.Task.Extensions` NuGet package, and 4.5.4 is the NuGet package version. Normally assembly version is used for <bindingRedirect> element. See this doc: [<bindingRedirect> Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/bindingredirect-element). Anyways, happy to know that your issue is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this solves your issue, I made a summary and hope this could also benefit other forum members who meet the similar/same issue.

For  element, consider using assembly version, instead of NuGet package version. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/bindingredirect-element) for details.

For `System.Threading.Task.Extensions` NuGet package, currently, 4.5.4 is the newest NuGet package version and 4.2.0.1 is the newest assembly version, so try to use 4.2.0.1.

[image]

Comment: where does this line go? You only show the necessary lines, so I have lost the context to where it should be placed.